# Why the geometrical frustration (spin ice model) has never been studied in superparamagnetic size range?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, spin-models

I'm trying to understand the effect of geometrical frustration in assembly of superparamagnetic nanoparticles but I can't find any reference. Does anyone know how magnetism can be affected by decreasing the size of nanomagnets down to superparamagnetic limit? Is there any significance to such studies?
The effect of geometrical frustration have long been studied in single domain ferromagnets and has been able to mimic the spin configurations of spin ice materials typically known as "artificial spin ice". But I can't find any studies that go below this limit and study the effect of geometrical features in smaller particles known as superparamagnetic particles and how their phase transition may or may not differ from their ferromagnetic counterparts. So my question is basically is there any reason beside limitations of fabrication methods that has caused this or are there other reasons why no one has ever been interested in such studies?